# How can i run a dockerized gui application on a virtual machine Ubuntu-Server?

Tags: server, docker

I have a Ubuntu-server running on VMWare that I use for testing purposes.
I'd like to run GUI applications in a docker container.
The situation is:

[image]

Spinning up the container works but I ain't getting a GUI .
If I `echo $DISPLAY` it returns empty.

Could someone explain in simple terms step-by-step how I can get the GUI displayed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a detailed guide, but I'll explain the concepts so you can go from there

You basically have two options:

- Use an existing X-server already running
- Use a VNC server inside the container

Ubuntu Server does not have a GUI backend (X-server) per default, so option 1 is not available unless you have installed an X-server.

It's probably easier to ensure your container provide its own VNC server, and then connect to the GUI with a remote desktop/VNC program.

See [more info here](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/).